# Windows C++ Multicast send

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, multicast

I'm strugling sending a multicast packet using Windows.

Below is my code:

```
SOCKET sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sd < 0) {
        perror("opening datagram socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockaddr_in service;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("225.1.1.1");
    service.sin_port = htons(56565);

    struct in_addr localInterface;
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.58");
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0) {
        perror("setting local interface");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string data = "AA";
    if (sendto(sd, data.c_str(), data.length(), 0, (const sockaddr*)&service, sizeof(service)) < 0)
        exit(0);
```

The code always exits on the setsockopt if. The 10.0.0.58 is my Wi-Fi card address. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does perror() print out?

Comment: it prints "No Error". If I ignore the exit, the sendto if also prints "No Error" but I can't catch the packet on Wireshark,

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if calling WSAGetLastError() would get you an error code that might give you more info about what is going wrong.

Comment: Have you get multi casting ever work before?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes, but not on C++ (C# is working fine).

Answer (score 0):

> *but I can't catch the packet on Wireshark*

If you never verified your WiFi network can handle IP mcast, similar issue, WiFi router configured to disable `multicast` IGMP packets! so you first check your WiFi router Settings IGMP section!

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I didn't knew about that. Nevertheless that is not the problem since it is working fine C#. The above code still doesn't work, but I got the problem working by using WinSock2 API.

Comment: @RicardoAlves Seriously? Winsock2 worked? I'm gonna try that, thanks!!